# How can I install additional packages in Java?

Tags: java

I am very new to Java. 
I would like to use some features from package called `daj`

The tutorial code has the following lines.

```
import daj.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import Msg;
```

But first and fourth lines produce red underscore such that program cannot compiles.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Where does this package come from? Do you have a jar file, or class files?

Comment: What is the IDE you are using?

Comment: I am using the Eclipese Java EE version..I just downloaded like an hour ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the packages to the classpath. If you are using an IDE as Eclipse or Netbeans, go to the project options and find the "Add library/jar" and they will take care of you.

You will need to add these libraries to the classpath both to compile and to run your program.

Also, the usual way of ordering imports is:

- first, java. packages
- second, javax. packagaes
- third party packages
- your packages

Comment: Hey just wondering, so in Java, there is no central system like Ruby-on-Rails's gem management system to take care of Jar packages files?

Comment: I do not know about RoR method but in Java it is just the classpath. There may be some tools on top of that (v.g. for packaging your classes with the libraries they need, or the IDEs maanging the classpath) but in the end it goes back to classpath.

Comment: Where is the `"Add library/jar"`?

Comment: @hhh go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path

Answer (score 1):

You need to have them in your build path.

Answer (score 0):

That daj package or jar file should be in your package or current directory or in classpath.